# Accessing Guid members in C#

Tags: c#, guid

In C++ we can access members of a guid in the following way:

```
GUID guid = {0};
CoCreateGuid(&guid);
dwRand = guid.Data1 & 0x7FFFFFFF;
```

The structure of guid in C++ is:

```
Data 1 - unsigned long
Data 2 - unsigned short
Data 3 - unsigned short
Data 4 - unsigned char
```

Question: How to translate the third line in the C++ code (`dwRand = guid.Data1 & 0x7FFFFFFF;`). In other words - how to access guid members? There's no such thing in C#.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this .NET C++, or standard C++?  If the latter, where are you getting your GUID class from?

Comment: FYI: since some (quite old) version of Windows, GUIDs aren't composed in a simple way from the MAC, date/time and randomizer number or whatever. Try generating a few GUIDs with guidgen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a structure:

```
public struct MyGuid
{
    public int Data1;
    public short Data2;
    public short Data3;
    public byte[] Data4;

    public MyGuid(Guid g)
    {
        byte[] gBytes = g.ToByteArray();
        Data1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(gBytes, 0);
        Data2 = BitConverter.ToInt16(gBytes, 4);
        Data3 = BitConverter.ToInt16(gBytes, 6);
        Data4 = new Byte[8];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(gBytes, 8, Data4, 0, 8);
    }

    public Guid ToGuid()
    {
        return new Guid(Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4);
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to modify a Guid:

```
Guid g = GetGuidFromSomewhere();
MyGuid mg = new MyGuid(g);
mg.Data1 &= 0x7FFFFFFF;
g = mg.ToGuid();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Guid.ToByteArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray.aspx) to get the values as bytes, but there are no accessor methods/properties for the "grouped" bytes. You could always write them as extension methods if you're using C# 3 though.